# Android app crash but don't restart to First activity

Tags: android, application-restart

My application is an Android launcher.
The application is very bad because the have many static.

My app crash a first time for a reason. The application is auto restared by the os; but it restart the activity crashed not the first activity and for this reason the app crash again because statics are initialized in the first activity.

Do you know how force the app to restart to the first activity ?

Thank's

> 06-14 17:29:20.544 12592-12620/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance V/FA: Using measurement service
>   06-14 17:29:20.544 12592-12620/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance V/FA: Connecting to remote service
>   06-14 17:29:20.544 12592-12592/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   06-14 17:29:20.544 12592-12592/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4177ebc0)
>   06-14 17:29:20.554 12592-12592/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance.sidebar_important_functionnality.SidebarService: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2828)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:166)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1365)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>                                                                                              at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                              at com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance.managers.PrefManager.isFrontBoard(PrefManager.java:163)
>                                                                                              at com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance.sidebar_important_functionnality.SidebarService.onCreate(SidebarService.java:77)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2818)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1365) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
>                                                                                              at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>   06-14 17:29:20.554 12592-12620/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
>   06-14 17:29:20.554 12592-12620/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, timestamp=1497454160564, fatal=1}]
>   06-14 17:29:20.574 12592-12620/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance V/FA: Using measurement service
>   06-14 17:29:20.574 12592-12620/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>   06-14 17:29:20.754 12592-12592/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance I/dalvikvm: Could not find method java.util.Locale.toLanguageTag, referenced from method bme.a
>   06-14 17:29:20.754 12592-12592/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10275: Ljava/util/Locale;.toLanguageTag ()Ljava/lang/String;
>   06-14 17:29:20.754 12592-12592/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00e4
>   06-14 17:29:20.784 12592-12592/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance, PID: 12592
>                                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance.sidebar_important_functionnality.SidebarService: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2828)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:166)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1365)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>                                                                                           at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
>                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                           at com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance.managers.PrefManager.isFrontBoard(PrefManager.java:163)
>                                                                                           at com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance.sidebar_important_functionnality.SidebarService.onCreate(SidebarService.java:77)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2818)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1365) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
>                                                                                           at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 
>                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>   06-14 17:29:20.804 12592-12626/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance I/FirebaseCrash: Sending crashes
>   06-14 17:29:21.475 12592-12626/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance I/FirebaseCrash: Response code: 200
>   06-14 17:29:21.475 12592-12626/com.sanilea.www.interfaceambulance I/FirebaseCrash: Report sent with crash report id: 9b9771a6d0000000

The first crash is me to post the logcat.

Comment: Post the logcat.

Comment: catch the NullPointerException you are getting.